# Dynamically Creating a Model from a Database table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Is there any way that a model can be built on the fly from and existing database table?

I initially thought a Dynamic Data site might be what I was after but I'm not a 100% convinced.

What I am trying to build is a website that lists items and properties.

The properties for the items will be the same, but as time goes on we may want to add more properties to each item, and rather than having to amend a data model and redeploying, was wondering if there were any alternatives.

For example, I would want to list items on a page

```
+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Item Name |       Description        |     Details     |
+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+
| Item 1    | A description for item 1 | Get the Details |
| Item 2    | A description for item 2 | Get the Details |
| Item 3    | A description for item 3 | Get the Details |
+-----------+--------------------------+-----------------+
```

and also a itemDetails table in the database like

```
+---------------+--------------------------+
|  Detail Name  |          Value           |
+---------------+--------------------------+
| Property Name | A description for item 1 |
+---------------+--------------------------+
```

and every item can have multiple itemDetails, and when viewing the itemDetails page it would iterate over all properties and values stored in the joined tables.

For example, item1 could end up like this

```
+---------+--------+
| Detail  | Value  |
+---------+--------+
| Size    | Large  |
| Colour  | Blue   |
| Height  | 1000CM |
| Weight  | 109 KG |
+---------+--------+
```

where Size, Colour, Height and Weight are rows in the itemDetails table.

Then, say we want to start tracking another attribute (eg Manufacturer), we insert that into the itemDetails table and then we can add to new instances and retrofit to older instances

Is this possible, and any good resources I could go to?